# What order do you add AudioUnit nodes in?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

With audio units you have to add the nodes to a graph like so...

```
AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &mixerUnitDescription, &mixerNode)
AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &outputUnitDescription, &outputNode)
```

Does the order of which node you call this on first change anything?  Or is it simple how you CONNECT the nodes that matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order doesn't matter, because an `AUGraph` can be reconfigured dynamically to add, remove, or alter node connections.  As you point out it's all about how the nodes are connected to each other.